# How to limit the Topic List to 5 (Items) after clicked to Show more (Button) show only 3 (Items)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

How to limit the ***Topic List*** to 5 (Items) after clicked to `Show more` (Button)only.

Also 3 (Items) and so on to the end of the list after that it shows you the `Show less` (Button).

***For example:*** In the Udemy filter option when you click in `See More` button it shows only ***5 items***.

This is my whole code :

***TEMPLATE CODE***

```
<template>
      <div class="modal fade" id="FilterPanelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="FilterPanelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body pb-0">
              <form>
                  <div class="row mb-xl-0 mb-lg-0 mb-3">

                  <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByTopic.FilterByTopic_Name" 
                            class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"> 
                          <i class="fas fa-folder mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByTopic.FilterByTopic_Title }}
                      </legend>
                      <div v-for="(Topic, Index) in FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions" 
                           v-bind:key="Topic.id"
                           class="filter-option-cnt">
                      <div v-if="Index < FilterByTopic_limit_by" 
                           class="filter-option">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" 
                             class="custom-control-input"
                             name="Filter-ByTopic"
                             v-model="FilterByTopic.FilterByT"
                             v-bind:id="Topic.Topic_UID"
                             :value="Topic.Topic_UID"
                             readonly />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" :for="Topic.Topic_UID">
                          {{ Topic.Topic_Name }} <small class="text-muted">{{ Topic.Topic_Count }}</small>
                      </label>
                      </div><!-- End custom-control -->
                      </div><!-- End filter-option -->
                      </div><!-- End filter-option-cnt -->
                      <button v-on:click="FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess(FilterByTopic_default_limit, FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions.length)" 
                              type="button"
                              class="btn btn-link pl-0">
                              <span v-if="FilterByTopic_limit_by === 5">
                                  <i class="fas fa-plus mr-1"></i>
                              </span>
                              <span v-else>
                                  <i class="fas fa-minus mr-1"></i>
                              </span>
                              {{ FilterByTopic_limit_by === 5 ? "See More" : "See Less" }}
                      </button>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

                  <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterBySubCategory.FilterBySubCategory_Name" 
                            class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title">
                          <i class="fas fa-tags mr-1"></i> {{ FilterBySubCategory.FilterBySubCategory_Title }}
                      </legend>
                      <div class="filter-option-cnt">

                      </div><!-- End filter-option-cnt -->
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

                  <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByLevel.FilterByLevel_Name" 
                            class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByLevel.FilterByLevel_Title }}</legend>

                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

                  <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByLanguage.FilterByLanguage_Name" 
                            class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-language mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByLanguage.FilterByLanguage_Title }}</legend>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

                  </div><!-- End row -->

                  <div class="row">

                  <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt mr-1"></i> Price</legend>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
                  <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-lightbulb mr-1"></i> Features</legend>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
                  <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i> Ratings</legend>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
                  <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-1"></i> Duration</legend>
                  </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

                  </div><!-- End row -->
              </form>
          </div><!-- End modal-body -->
          </div><!-- End modal-content -->
          </div><!-- End modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- End FilterPanelModal -->
    </template>
```

***SCRIPT CODE***

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'FilterPanelModal',
    data: function() {
        return {
            // For Filter By Topic
            FilterByTopic_default_limit: 5,
            FilterByTopic_limit_by: 5,
            FilterByTopic: {
                FilterByTopic_Title: "Topic",
                FilterByTopic_Name: "Topic",
                FilterByT: [],
                FilterByTopicOptions: [
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 0, 
                        Topic_UID: "JXETdWWM",
                        Topic_Name: "Ionic",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 1, 
                        Topic_UID: "g2K8SkFA",
                        Topic_Name: "PHP",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 2, 
                        Topic_UID: "P1Q6HOFN",
                        Topic_Name: "Python",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 3, 
                        Topic_UID: "rMzXsrwO",
                        Topic_Name: "Ruby & Rails",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 4, 
                        Topic_UID: "IaMfmedm",
                        Topic_Name: ".NET / C#",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 5, 
                        Topic_UID: "kAqpieja",
                        Topic_Name: "Java",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 6, 
                        Topic_UID: "rUf0AGyV",
                        Topic_Name: "Perl",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 7, 
                        Topic_UID: "znaJ4diW",
                        Topic_Name: "ColdFusion",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 8, 
                        Topic_UID: "uXmoqYpc",
                        Topic_Name: "JavaScript",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 9, 
                        Topic_UID: "daL54tCv",
                        Topic_Name: "ActionScript",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 10, 
                        Topic_UID: "GiXDC0oe",
                        Topic_Name: "Angular",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 11, 
                        Topic_UID: "AvNhruTX",
                        Topic_Name: "C++",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 12, 
                        Topic_UID: "tUxVxhHH",
                        Topic_Name: "SQL",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 13, 
                        Topic_UID: "kfvzVRsH",
                        Topic_Name: "MySQL",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 14, 
                        Topic_UID: "wSeLABXD",
                        Topic_Name: "MongoDB",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 15, 
                        Topic_UID: "SuqxZbEM",
                        Topic_Name: "Dart",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 16, 
                        Topic_UID: "BwAXbUmp",
                        Topic_Name: "Haskell",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 17, 
                        Topic_UID: "cHSjfDKs",
                        Topic_Name: "Kotlin",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 18, 
                        Topic_UID: "PEpWCdtF",
                        Topic_Name: "Ruby",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 19, 
                        Topic_UID: "RWMKGkCj",
                        Topic_Name: "NodeJS",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 20, 
                        Topic_UID: "NqHzgDWS",
                        Topic_Name: "Wordpress",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    }
                ]
            }, // End Filter By Topic

            // For Filter By SubCategory
            FilterBySubCategory: {
                FilterBySubCategory_Title: "Subcategory",
                FilterBySubCategory_Name: "Subcategory",
                FilterBySubCat: [],
                FilterBySubCategoryOptions: []
            },
            // End Filter By SubCategory

            // For Filter By Level
            FilterByLevel: {
                FilterByLevel_Title: "Level",
                FilterByLevel_Name: "Level",
                FilterByLv: [],
                FilterByLevelOptions: []
            },
            // End Filter By Level

            // For Filter By Language
            FilterByLanguage: {
                FilterByLanguage_Title: "Language",
                FilterByLanguage_Name: "Language",
                FilterByLang: [],
                FilterByLanguageOptions: []
            }
            // End Filter By Language

        }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
        FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess (FilterByTopic_default_limit, filters_length) {
            this.FilterByTopic_limit_by = (this.FilterByTopic_limit_by === FilterByTopic_default_limit) ? filters_length : FilterByTopic_default_limit;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess is wrong, what you want to do here is increase the number of topics you display until you are showing all of the topics, then return to initial state.

```
FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess (limit, total) {
          if(this.FilterByTopic_limit_by >= total)
            this.FilterByTopic_limit_by = limit;
          else
            this.FilterByTopic_limit_by += limit;
        }
```

Now just change the condition for the button label.

```
{{ FilterByTopic_limit_by === FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions.length ? "See More" : "See Less" }}
```

Comment: it's work for me bro but instead of showing it to me (See more) it show me (See Less) how I can change it to see more?